# Crystal Reports Multiple Line Charts

Tags: charts, crystal-reports

I'm using Crystal Reports and I am having issues...

I have a sample database that has ITEMS, DATE, and VALUE.

I want to make two line charts, the first one trending the value of one item over time and the second trending the value of a second item over time. It seemed simple enough to make a single chart. I just used a selection formula for item 1 and added the chart with the right data. However, I can't figure out how to add a second chart, such that the first chart will display item 1 and the second will display item 2. Adding item 2 to the selection formula just combines the data into two duplicate charts (understandably). How do you associate each chart will a subset of the report data.

Comment: how are you adding items to charts? what formulas are you using?

Comment: I'm just pulling data where item = item1 or item = item2 with a selection formula.